# ReactJS is there a way to change the title text on an event trigger in a Plotly js plot?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, plotly.js

When I create the plot, I give it a layout parameter and I know I can set an x-axis title but I would like to change the x-axis title based on which plot I'm showing based on an event trigger.

Where I create the plot: (Plotting.js)

```
<Plot
            data={[]}
            revision={this.state.revision}
            config = {{displayModeBar: true, modeBarButtonsToRemove: ["lasso2d", "select2d", "zoom2d", "resetScale2d"], displaylogo: false}}
            layout= {{
              xaxis: {
                range: [State.values.xMin, State.values.xMax],
                title: {
                  text: "The text I'm trying to change is here"
                }
              }
            }}
/>
```

Where I want to update the plot: (StatisticField.js)

```
export default function StatisticsDropDown() {
    return (
        <Select onChange={(event) => {
            State.values.PlotInfo.Fields = event.target.value
            //console.log(document.getElementById("updater").innerHTML )
            let e = {target: {value: ""}}
            document.getElementById("min").value = 0
            document.getElementById("max").value = 0
            
            
            if(State.values.PlotInfo.Fields === "1"){
                Plot.layout.title.text = State.values.PlotInfo.Fields + " mA"
            }
            else if(State.values.PlotInfo.Fields === "2"){
                Plot.layout.title.text = State.values.PlotInfo.Fields + " dB"
            }
            else if(State.values.PlotInfo.Fields === "3"){
                Plot.layout.title.text = State.values.PlotInfo.Fields + " dBm"
            }
            else if(State.values.PlotInfo.Fields === "4"){
                Plot.layout.title.text = State.values.PlotInfo.Fields + " ps"
            }
            else if(State.values.PlotInfo.Fields === "5"){
                Plot.layout.title.text = State.values.PlotInfo.Fields + " dBm"
            }
            else if(State.values.PlotInfo.Fields === "6"){
                Plot.layout.title.text = State.values.PlotInfo.Fields + " dB"
            }
            else{
                Plot.layout.title.text = "broken very sad"
            }
            window.testing.createPlot(e)
        }}>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option> 
        </Select>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a state manager so that the component renders again when its value changes.

Capture the selected value StatisticsDropDown by using useState.

```
const [type, setType] = useState();
```

For the StatisticsDropDown component, update type value when values changes by:

```
  <select onChange={(e)= setType(e.target.value)}>
<option value="mA">mA</option>
<option value="dB">dB</option>
</select>
```

Then, you can set Plot title dynamically reading type value.

```
<Plot
            data={[]}
            revision={this.state.revision}
            config = {{displayModeBar: true, modeBarButtonsToRemove: ["lasso2d", "select2d", "zoom2d", "resetScale2d"], displaylogo: false}}
            layout= {{
              xaxis: {
                range: [State.values.xMin, State.values.xMax],
                title: {
                  text: type
                }
              }
            }}
/>
```